# flask-login invalidates session randomly after authentication

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using flask-login https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest for session management. The user first login in (login.html) the application and go to home.html. However, after the user has authenticated and click different links, it will kick out the session and go back to login page. This happens very randomly and I'm not sure what went wrong? It is using apache. It seems okay with localhost but having this issue in apache. Are there specific apache configurations need to pay attention?

Please advise how to fix this issue? Thanks so much!!

```
    class User(UserMixin):
       pass

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
       print "load_user...." + user_id
       user = User()
       user.id = user_id
       return user

    @app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        #login procedure
        curr_user = User()
        curr_user.id = LOGIN_USERNAME
        login_user(curr_user)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    @app.route("/")
    @app.route("/home")
    @login_required
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I found this answer which seems to have solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57162593/5424359
Basically, you need to make sure you set app.secret_key to some secret key. A simple way to get a key is as follows.

```
>>>import os
>>>os.urandom(24)
```

Take that number and set app.secret_key to it. Make sure you don't have the app generating a key every time.

Answer (score 0):

The function for route `/` does not validate for user's session and just returns the template for login.

Either modify your `loading()` function

```
from flask import url_for

@app.route("/")
def loading():
    return redirect(url_for('.home'))
```

Or do validation whether user is logged in

```
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route("/")
def loading():
   if current_user.is_authenticated:
       return render_template('home.html')
   else:
       return render_template('login.html')
```

Or

Remove the `loading()` funtion and add the `/` route to `home()`

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

This way when ever the route `/` or `/home` is requested, flask validates the login (as `@login_required` decorator is present). If not logged in, `login_view` defined for `LoginManager` will be rendered.

```
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(flask_app)
lm.login_view = '/login'
```

Comment: Thanks @frankinsijo. Is flask-login multi-thread? I am having trouble that it got kick out from time to time after login, it does not matter single user or multiple user. any idea why? I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731938/does-flask-login-support-multiple-users-and-sessions-concurrency in here already

Comment: Yes it supports multiple sessions. By kick out from time to time you mean the user gets logged out automatically? If so, i believe some piece of code in your application is invalidating the session unless you have modified the `permanent_session_lifetime` value.

Comment: thanks franklinsijo. I did not use permanent_session_lifetime so it should not have any session timeout by default? I updated the code in this post, and it will run `@login_manager.unauthorized_handler` randomly to kick out the session back to login page, please help out see what you think. Do I need to implement `@login_manager.request_loader` too? Also `{{curr_user.id}}` print None, not the login username

Comment: I just added `@login_manager.request_loader`. But sometimes will call `@login_manager.user_loader` but sometimes `@login_manager.request_loader`. any idea why? I posted the code too

Comment: I tested more, if I added `def request_loader(request)` I never got session logged out but also no need to login. If I removed `def request_loader(request)` then I always got kicked out of sessions but it is still randomly. any ideas why? thanks so much!!

Comment: I believe you are complicating it. Add a `return` statement to the `login()` method. Something like `return redirect(url_for('.home'))` and AFAIK `@login_manager.request_loader` is not required here.

Comment: thanks. I did have return home in `login()`. Do I need `@login_manager.unauthorized_handler` too? I realized if I removed it is better. Now I removed both `@login_manager.unauthorized_handler` and `@login_manager.request_loader` This is just regular LDAP login on the web form

Comment: Also, am I supposed to use `app.run(threaded=True)` for multi-user sessions?

Comment: Setting threaded to true will let you to manage each session in seperate thread.

Comment: I assumed the app was not logging the user in as the login method did not return after the POST.

Comment: I have `return redirect(url_for('home'))` in the code. I added `return redirect(url_for('home'))` in this login method of this post.

Comment: Do I need `@login_manager.unauthorized_handler` too? Now I removed both `@login_manager.unauthorized_handler` and `@login_manager.request_loader` I only keep `@login_manager.user_loader` This is just regular LDAP login on the web form. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: No you do not need them. From these comments I understand that you are trying to achieve a regular Login Form functionality with Flask login, it can be done without these handlers and loaders.

Comment: thanks. I have updated the post. It is still happening but randomly. But when I tested with localhost it seems okay, but having issue in apache server. any specific configurations for flask?

Comment: @JennyB I am also facing the same issue on the google app engine but working fine on localhost, can you please suggest what did you do to fix this in your case? Please help