# Random logouts with flask-login on IIS with FastCGI

Tags: python-3.x, iis, fastcgi, plotly-dash, wfastcgi

I'm running a Dash/Flask app on Windows Server 2019 with IIS. I installed IIS with CGI, installed wfastcgi in the app's virtual environment, ran wfastcgi-enable as an administrator and specified the FastCGI application as a route handler in web.config using the virtual environment's python executable and wfastcgi.py file, etc.

That all went smoothly and the app is up and running. The app redirects to '/' to login if the user is logged out. This all works perfectly when I run the app on Flask's built-in server, but only works periodically (i.e. sometimes the user is no longer logged in, after the redirect, or refreshing the page logs out the user by chance) in this IIS/fastcgi setup. I use flask-login to login and authenticate users, following closely the example given here: https://github.com/RafaelMiquelino/dash-flask-login.

I also tried to configure flask-login's remember me functionality to persist the login after browser close, but this didn't change the mentioned issues.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm open to any ideas on why I'm experiencing this strange (session?) behavior with IIS and FastCGI.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Moreover, I did some more tests and found that it is not only random logouts, but also some kind of "random logins": 
1. User logs in at login page and is redirected to the "real" content located under /success: Message: User could not be authenticated. 
2. Reloading the webpage "/success" without any further action: User is authenticated and can see the content. After repeated reloading the same user is randomly authenticated or not.

Comment: I am having the same problem. After less than 5 minutes all users get logged out. Have you found a solution? I am almost configuring a Linux server to avoid Microsoft's BS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the iis application pool recycling and ideal time out value.

[image]

increase fast cgi ideal time out:

[image]

Make sure you set app.secret_key to some secret key. yo could get key by following below code:

```
import os
os.urandom(24)
```

Use the following command to quickly generate a value for Flask.secret_key (or SECRET_KEY):

```
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.urandom(16))'
b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'
```

Refer this link for more detail:

[flask-login invalidates session randomly after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670136/flask-login-invalidates-session-randomly-after-authentication)

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! - I doubled the Idle Timeout for both, the FastCGI Application and the application pool, doubled the application pool recycling time interval, but both did not change the behaviour. Furthermore I increased the size fo the random key from 12 to 24, but also no change.

Comment: Moreover, I investigated further and it is not only random logouts, but sometimes after reloading the page, a user which was authenticated at the very beginning, but seemed to be logged out again, is logged in again, i.e.: 
- User logs in and is redirected to the "real" content: Message: User could not be authenticated. Only reloading the webapge: User is authenticated and can see the content.

Comment: @abirnkraut which python version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.6